# One homomorphism to another in group under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n \geq 2$, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which is a group under addition. There is a function $\phi_{\bar{a}}(\bar{x}):G \rightarrow G$ for every $\bar{a} \in G$, with $\phi_{\bar{a}}(\bar{x})=\bar{a} \cdot \bar{x}$.

Now I'm asked to prove that every homomorphism $\psi: G\rightarrow G$ equals some $\phi_{\bar{a}}$. I've already established $\phi_{\bar{a}}$ is a homomorphism.

Since $\psi$ is a homomorphism I know that $\psi(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=\psi(\bar{x})+\psi(\bar{y})$ but I have no idea how to tie this to $\phi_{\bar{a}}$. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Hint:** $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Given a homomorphism $f:G\to G$ write $\bar{a}=f(1)$. Now use the properties of a homomorphism.

Comment: the only property I'm aware of is the one stated. How to apply this to your hint? I would say letting $\bar{a}=1$ would mean that you add $\bar{1}$ to the $\bar{x}$, which would let you cycle through all $\bar{a} \in G$.

Comment: Well, for some $b\in\mathbb{Z_n}$, what is $f(b)$? You can write $b=1+...+1$ (add $b$ times) and hence $f(b)=f(1)+...+f(1)=f(1)\times b$. Of course this is all mod $n$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. This would then lead to the conclusion that only $\bar{a}=\bar{1}$ is isomorphic, since all larger $\bar{a}$ would 'skip' some elements in $G$. Correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. But what we get is that letting $\bar{a}=f(1)$ we can conclude that $f(b)=f(1)\times b=a\times b$ for all $b\in\mathbb{Z_n}$. So $f=\phi_{\bar{a}}$.

Comment: Does this mean you use $f(b)=f(1 \cdot b)=f(1) \cdot f(b) = a \cdot f(b)$? But how can you conclude $f(b)=b$?

Comment: No, I use that $f(b)=f(1+...+1)=f(1)+...+f(1)=f(1)\times b$. We don't get $f(b)=b$, we get $f(b)=f(1)\times b$.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it. Little slow on the abstract algebra, sorry for making you spit it out like this. Appreciate it though!